# why greedy:true in jquery ui droppable not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create a jquery ui droppable and have 3 droppable elements that are children.

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
<div id="droppable1" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p>Dropp here</p>

  <div id="droppable2" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
    <p>Dropp here</p>
    <div id="droppable3" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
      <p>Dropp here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

when drop an element on first parent, all children elements drop function will work, i want when greedy set true, draggable element don't drop in droppable's children but children droppable function work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
   $("#draggable").draggable({});
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
  greedy: true,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
  $(this)
    .find("p")

    .html(" Dropped! " + event.target.id);
  }
 });
 var status = $(".droppable").droppable("option", "greedy");
 $('#d1').html(" <b>Status of greedy </b>: " + status);
 $("input:radio[name=r1]").click(function() {
 var sel = ($(this).val() == 'true');
 $(".droppable").droppable("option", "greedy", sel);
 var status = $(".droppable").droppable("option", "greedy");
 $('#d1').html(" <b>Status of greedy </b>: " + status);
})
})
```

here my code https://jsfiddle.net/taher24/Lbxw0k1y/

Comment: Please put the complete code here in your question, not just in an external JSFiddle; that includes the JavaScript.  Additionally, your link to your fiddle does not work when I click on it.

Comment: sorry, i fix jsfiddle link